# Autoresize ListBox inside ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, user-controls, scrollviewer

In my application I have a `Window`. It contains a left side menu, a header and a place for content.

This content is being loaded dynamically - a `UserControl` is put in there. These `UserControls` are various. From just a `TextBlock` to quite complex pages. To make sure all the content will be visible I have to wrap it with a `ScrollViewer` (I mean in MyWindow.xaml). It all works fine until I need to put a `ListView` in the content.

More or less the code looks like that:

```
<ScrollViewer> // this is the wrapping viewer actually it's in a different file
    <UserControl>
        ......
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Value}" Text="{Binding WorkOrderNumber}"/>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Value}" Text="{Binding ActionType}"/>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Value}" Text="{Binding StartDate}"/>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Value}" Text="{Binding StopDate}"/>
                            <Separator/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Whatever.. Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource CustomButton}" Content="Previous" />
                <Button Style="{StaticResource CustomButton}" Content="Current" />
                <Button Style="{StaticResource CustomButton}" Content="Next" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The result is that the listbox has no scrollbar and gets vary high. The scrollbar is only at the window's scrollviewer.

So in my UserControl I want:

- the buttons always to be at the very bottom
- the listbox to fill the whole space left (also to resize along with the window)
- avoid hardcoding listbox's height

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use a DockPanel instead of a Grid. DockPanel has a property called LastChhildFill. It is by default true. If you set your ListBox to be the last Child, it will fill all the space:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource CustomButton}"
                    Content="Previous" />
            <Button Style="{StaticResource CustomButton}"
                    Content="Current" />
            <Button Style="{StaticResource CustomButton}"
                    Content="Next" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView >
        </ListView>
    </DockPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

But this setting makes the Buttons to disappear. I mean they are always at the Bottom of the ListBox. So maybe you need to **remove the ScrollViewer**.